# Submit AJAX via POST to asp.net page with multiple Form.Request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Is there a way to send different ajax requests to the same ASPX page? I've tried using multiple Context.Request.Form and it does not seem to work.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/submit.aspx",
        data: "request="
});

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/submit.aspx",
        data: "request2="
});
```

The submit.aspx page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim email_Request As New Thread(
        Sub()
            Dim Request As String = Context.Request.Form("request")

            ' email code here

        End Sub
    )
    email_Request.Start()

    Dim email_Request2 As New Thread(
        Sub()
            Dim Request2 As String = Context.Request.Form("request2")

            ' email code here

        End Sub
    )
    email_Request2.Start()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your client code does two separate requests and that will be handled separately on the server. However your server code expects one request with two parameters `request` and `request2`. Which option do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need threads in your case, IIS takes care of that. Just do different operations depending on the querystring.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim Request As String = Context.Request.Form("request")
    Dim Request2 As String = Context.Request.Form("request2")


    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request) Then
       ' ...
    Else If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request2) Then
       ' ...    
    End If

End Sub
```